# Packaging jre 7 binary file license questions?

Tags: java, license, jre

Notice jre and jdk 7 have new license agreement. Am I able to include binary jre without additional license?

Comment: Please, do notice that **we are not** in any way **lawers** and you may need legal advice to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you include the binary you will also need to include the new license (and abide by it yourself).

See also: http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/distribution.xml

> **Can I distribute Java with my software?**
>
> Yes, you can provide Java with your software provided you abide by the terms and conditions of Java binary code [license](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/distribution.xml#eula).

Answer (score 1):

According to Oracle:

LICENSE TO USE. Subject to the terms and conditions of this Agreement including, but not limited to, the Java Technology Restrictions of the Supplemental License Terms, Oracle grants you a non-exclusive, non-transferable, limited license without license fees to reproduce and use internally the Software complete and unmodified for the sole purpose of running Programs. THE LICENSE SET FORTH IN THIS SECTION 2 DOES NOT EXTEND TO THE COMMERCIAL FEATURES.

<sup>Source:[License Agreement for the Java SE Platform](http://www.google.jo/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2Ftechnetwork%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2Fdocumentation%2Fbcl-for-java-se-397068.pdf&ei=jLV7Uvy2K6yA7Qbcn4GwDA&usg=AFQjCNFuFQBb14fuDwUJ1ifg61D18Klvbw&bvm=bv.56146854,d.ZG4&cad=rja)</sup>

Comment: Does this mean we can not use java for commercial? And we only can use internally.

Comment: I'm not an Attorney, but from the document you need to get permission from Oracle.  Also you may want to look at OpenJDK.

Comment: @王子1986: I don't think so. The term **commercial features** has a special meaning in the [license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html). It refers to features listed in Table 1-1 in the [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/products/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/distribution.xml:

> Can I distribute Java with my software?
>
> Yes, you can provide Java with your software provided you abide by the
>   terms and conditions of Java binary code license.

Comment: From another answer on the same page: "You may make Java available to users within your organization on a CD. And you may distribute Java bundled with your application to users outside of your organization. You may not distribute Java alone on a CD."